# Whats the best way to select fields from multiple tables with a common prefix?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sensor data from a client which is in ongoing acquisition. Every week we get a table of new data (about one million rows each) and each table has the same prefix. I'd like to run a query and select some columns across all of these tables.

what would be the best way to go about this ?

I have seen some solutions that use dynammic sql and i was considering writing a stored procedure that would form a dynamic sql statement and execute it for me. But im not sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Postgresql. This is an *ideal* case for [**partitioning**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html) with constraint exclusion based on dates. You create one master table *without data*, and the other tables added daily inherit from it. In your case, you don't even have to worry about the nuisance of triggers on INSERT; sounds like there is never any insertion other than the daily bulk creation of a new table. See the link above for full documentation.

Queries can be run against the *parent* table, and Postgres takes care of looking in all the child tables, *plus* it is smart enough to skip child tables ruled out by `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: Actually our client set this relation up in the database and i was wondering if thats how it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, sometimes you have to write dynamic SQL to handle cases such as this.

If all of your tables are loaded you can query for table names within your stored procedure.  Something like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Play with that to get the specific table names you need.

How are the table names differentiated?  By date?  Some incrementing ID?

Comment: Yeah, i know how to build the dynamic sql string. but i was wondering if there was a better way because its actually performance critical. Thanks for the help !.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the meta data for tables with the same prefix.

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'week%'
```

Then you could use `union all` to combine queries like

```
select * from week001
union all
select * from week002
[...]
```

However I suggest appending new records to one single table, and use an index on the timestamp column. This would especially speed up queries which span multiple weeks etc. It will simplify your queries a lot, if you only have to deal with one table. If the table is getting too large, you could partition by date etc. So there should be no need to partition manually by having multiple tables.